# Update statement makes Datagrip complain about missing WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

I'm playing around with a DB and I'm generating random data to test my frontend. Everytime I wish to set every row a certain way I write

```sql
UPDATE medley
SET option = true
```

At this point Datagrip complains about a missing WHERE clause warning me that my query will update the whole table. But that's what I want!
Is there any generic WHERE clause that I can use like `WHERE any`?

For now I've added an ID so that I can `WHERE id >= 0` but I was curious if there were any alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In DataGrip, there is a settings you need to change.
It will prevent you from running these queries and also show you the warning beforehand.

```
Unsafe query: Update statement without where clause updates all table rows
```

You will get the error: Error code: 1175 because you are using the safe mode.

To disable the safe mode:

```
toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a where clause that is always true:

```
UPDATE medley
  SET option = true
WHERE true;
```

Comment: Very useful! But the other answer is more on point

Answer (score 1):

After you run this kind of query, there are options to *Execute* and *Execute and supress*

[image]